# Animation not working Unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

So I upgraded my project to unity 5 but now ALL animations on the project just don't work !!! whats the problem

Every thing was working fine before upgrading to unity 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using curves try deselect the option "apply root motion" on the animator.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there were major changes in animation. So it could be a lot of things. My animations did work after upgrading, so it's not a global problem.

[Try looking trough the release notes](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an animation and I found it is related to the 'Static Batching' feature present in Unity 5. Here is how I solved it:

1. Select the object you are animating.
2. In the Top-Right corner of the Inspector window you'll see a drop down list near to the Static label, click on it.
3. Uncheck the 'Batching Static' option.

Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: quick remark. Make sure your input detection is set inside an Update() and not FixedUpdate() as FixedUpdate() is normally used for physics and will not tolerate your animation if located within

Answer (score 0):

My english not good, but I'm found answer!
Choose your object and it top will be 3 line, press that!Choose debug and do this [and do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meq8R.png)

Comment: It would be nice if you could describe your steps in your answer in addition to the image.

Answer (score 0):

try change Animation update mode to unscaled time